# If I need to divide several numbers by the same value, is it better that I calculate the inverse first?

Tags: c++

Every now and then in code it comes up that I need to divide several numbers by the same value:

```
double d = divisor();

double a = firstNum() / d;
double b = secondNum() / d;
double c = thirdNum() / d;
```

Since multiplication is faster than division I will often write this as

```
double di = 1 / divisor();

double a = firstNum() * di;
double b = secondNum() * di;
double c = thirdNum() * di;
```

I'm wondering if I'm really saving any time by doing this.  Would my compiler be smart enough to do this automatically?  Is it worth making my code a little less readable?

Comment: Don't pay the price of losing readability unless this particular block of code is in the critical path for performance.

Comment: Why don't you measure the two codes and find out for yourself?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is not allowed to transform the first fragment to the second, or vice versa, because floating point arithmetic is finicky and these fragments are not precisely equivalent.

Whether or not you are saving anything by doing it yourself depends on the hardware and other factors. Only testing with your compiler on your hardware within your larger software can tell. Chances are, if you are wondering which one is faster, then the difference is not noticeable.

If you *know for sure* that the more readable code is so much slower that it *fails to fulfil performance requirements*, you may consider changing it to less readable faster code.